# Angular2: Shortcut keys using HostListener vs Mousetrap

Tags: angular, keyboard-shortcuts, mousetrap, angular-hotkeys

I am working on an Angular2 project wherein I want to incorporate Shortcut keys for various functionalities.

I am confused between two approaches. One is to create shortcuts by using HostListener as below :

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleHotkey(event: KeyboardEvent){
  ... 
}
```

The other approach is to use [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) JS framework and then create a service around it which is customized to my project as done in [angular2-hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-hotkeys).

Some Pros according to me  of using Mousetrap over Hostlistener -

1. A common service to add/remove/pause/unpause shortcuts.
2. Reading of hotkeys from a config file.
3. Ease of coding and maintenance.

Which would be a better approach for angular2.

I am especially concerned about degraded performance.